# C# - Recommendations for extracting files from .tgz file

Tags: c#

I've got a Windows C# program that I want to extract a file (or directory) from a .tgz file without compromising the integrity of the .tgz file.  This file comes from a linux system and has permissions set on it and what I need to do is remove a directory from it, and then send it to another linux machine to run.  I tried using the Chilkat component but it removed all the permissions and casing on the sub folders so it wouldn't run on the other linux box.

Any suggestions as to how I can do this (if it can be done on a Windows machine using C#) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Decompress nested GZip (TGZ) files in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755843/how-to-decompress-nested-gzip-tgz-files-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [sharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/), I have used it in the passed with success